packer 'Build 'vsphere-iso.image' errored after 61 milliseconds 117 microseconds: POST "//sdk": 400 Bad Request'
I'm building an OVF ubuntu-2022 image for vsphere with packer. The end goal is to create a bootable OVF image which will then be used to quickly boot virtual machines.
I run the following command:
packer build -var vsphere_username=$VSPHERE_USER -var vsphere_password=$VSPHERE_PASSWORD base-ubuntu-22.04.4-vSphere.pkr.hcl
`
here is the code:
locals {
  vm_name          = "base-ubuntu-${var.distro_version}-cloudimg-${var.env}-${formatdate("YYYYMMDDss", timestamp())}.ovf"
  output_directory = "../../artifacts/vsphere/ubuntu-${var.distro_version}-${var.env}"
}
source "vsphere-iso" "image" {

  // Virtual Machine Settings
  vm_name              = local.vm_name
  guest_os_type        = "ubuntu64Guest"
  firmware             = "bios"
  CPUs                 = var.cpu_count
  cpu_cores            = "1" # Number of CPU cores per socket.
  RAM                  = var.memory_size
  disk_controller_type = ["scsi"]
  storage {
    disk_size             = var.disk_size
    disk_thin_provisioned = false
  }
  network_adapters {
    network = "DMZ-INT"
  }
  iso_checksum         = "0532a2daa66a7bce1bfadab2924597522eda5591"
  iso_url              = "https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/${var.distro_codename}/current/${var.distro_codename}-server-cloudimg-amd64.vmdk"
  iso_target_extension = "vmdk"

  boot_wait = "10s"
  boot_command = [
    // This waits for 3 seconds, sends the "c" key, and then waits for another 3 seconds. In the GRUB boot loader, this is used to enter command line mode.
    "<wait3s>c<wait3s>",
    // This types a command to load the Linux kernel from the specified path with the 'autoinstall' option and the value of the 'data_source_command' local variable.
    "linux /casper/vmlinuz --- autoinstall ds=\"nocloud\"",
    // This sends the "enter" key and then waits. This is typically used to execute the command and give the system time to process it.
    "<enter><wait>",
    // This types a command to load the initial RAM disk from the specified path.
    "initrd /casper/initrd",
    // This sends the "enter" key and then waits. This is typically used to execute the command and give the system time to process it.
    "<enter><wait>",
    // This types the "boot" command. This starts the boot process using the loaded kernel and initial RAM disk.
    "boot",
    // This sends the "enter" key. This is typically used to execute the command.
    "<enter>"
  ]
  cd_files          = ["./files/cloud-init/*"]
  ip_settle_timeout = "10s" # Amount of time to wait for VM's IP to settle down
  shutdown_command  = "echo 'packer' | sudo -E shutdown -P now"

  // Communicator Settings and Credentials
  communicator = "ssh"
  ssh_username = "ubuntu"
  ssh_password = "ubuntu"
  ssh_port     = "22"

  vcenter_server = "{my-vcenter_server}"
  username = var.vsphere_username
  password = var.vsphere_password
  insecure_connection = true
  cluster = "var.cluster"
  folder = "Templates"
  datacenter = "var.datacenter"
  host = "var.host" 
  datastore = "var.datastore"

}

build {
  sources = ["source.vsphere-iso.image"]

  provisioner "shell" {
    // run scripts with sudo, as the default cloud image user is unprivileged
    execute_command = "echo 'packer' | sudo -S sh -c '{{ .Vars }} {{ .Path }}'"
    scripts = [
      "./scripts/base-vsphere.sh",
    ]
  }
}

All variables have been defined.
Here is the output:
vsphere-iso.image: output will be in this color.

    vsphere-iso.image: Closing sessions ....
Build 'vsphere-iso.image' errored after 177 milliseconds 986 microseconds: POST "//sdk": 400 Bad Request

==> Wait completed after 178 milliseconds 39 microseconds

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> vsphere-iso.image: POST "//sdk": 400 Bad Request

==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.

Does anyone have an idea for a solution? I checked all fields. I don't know what to check anymore.
